# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected double-quote mark PHP

Tags: php, html, syntax-error

I'm new to php, I have been getting this error in my code

```
echo "<a href=\"PHadmin_deletePatient.php?id=<?php echo $row["PatientID"]; ?>\" class='delete' title='Delete' data-toggle='tooltip'><i class='material-icons'>&#xE872;</i></a>";
```

I found out that the error is within `?id=<?php echo $row["PatientID"]; ?>` this part of the code but I couldn't solve it.

Full error- Parse error: syntax error, unexpected double-quote mark, expecting "-" or identifier or variable or number in

Comment: What error? Please post the code before and the actual error but first [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: You do not need to use `<?php echo $row["PatientID"]; ?>` within an existing echo statement

Comment: `echo "<a href='PHadmin_deletePatient.php?id={$row["PatientID"]}' class='delete' title='Delete' data-toggle='tooltip'><i class='material-icons'>&#xE872;</i></a>";` - the variable, when encased within double-quotes, will be parsed correctly so you can simply include it within the string ~ the use of curly quotes around the variable is mainly optional

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write echo inside the already present PHP echo code.
Update your code and try to use single quotes if you double quote for your attribute.

```
echo '<a href="PHadmin_deletePatient.php?id='.$row['PatientID'].'" class="delete" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE872;</i> </a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes. Write this

echo "<a href='PHadmin_deletePatient.php?id=' class='delete' title='Delete' data-toggle='tooltip'>";

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you want to do. You want to print link html with echo and you don't want quotation marks to be a problem.

```php
echo '<a href="testlink">Test Link</a>';

// or

echo "<a href='testlink'>Test Link</a>";
```

Above I showed both ways to get rid of quotation marks. If you are going to use double quotes in echo, echo should start with single quotes. If you are going to use single quotes, it should start with double quotes.

If my answer worked please mark as correct